# Python Bytes to string to Bytes

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, character-encoding, python-unicode

I know something similar has been asked before, but no answer has yet worked.

I make a byte string:
   `salt = os.urandom(16)` 
which gives something like:
`b'w\x05\xce^f\xdcbM\xe9\xb8c\x8b\x98\xd2\n\x11'`

What I need is to give this to the user, so they can copy and paste, place it in a text document or anywhere, and then paste it back in the terminal later.

In short. I need to convert it to a string. And then back to its encoding.

I have tried `salt.decode(encoding="utf-8")` and many variations which all give me some form of `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't...`, The only one that seemed to work was `"".join(map(chr, salt))`, but I can't figure out how to reverse this.

Thanks in advance. P.s. I am working in Python 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python module `binsascii` is most likely what you need. Example:

```
>>> import os
>>> salt = os.urandom(16)
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.b2a_hex(salt)
'9df7cc8d135fb9f115e166e140153217'
>>> binascii.a2b_hex(binascii.b2a_hex(salt))
'\x9d\xf7\xcc\x8d\x13_\xb9\xf1\x15\xe1f\xe1@\x152\x17'
```

A number of other encodings are also available.